# Android PeriodicWorkRequest only firing once? is ID changing? Should I use Tag?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am attempting to run a Job in my android app every minute (polling a piece of web data for changes)

I follow this tutorial : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-periodicity-ff35185ff006

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
                   .setRequiredNetworkTypes(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                   .build()

val request = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<RetrieveDataWorker>(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag("GETTINGDATA")
            .build()

WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Getdata", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request)


WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(request.id)
    .observe(this, Observer {
        val status: String = it.state.name
        Toast.makeText(this,status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })
```

I can confirm the basic single enqueue works fine and I am happy... it even fires once using this periodic technique.. but never more than once.  is it my emulator?

Edit: I have debugged my worker and the debugger only ever goes into the function once.. and never again

Comment: According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) **The repeat interval must be greater than or equal to PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS.** When the interval passed is less then `MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` then it is set to `MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS`. `MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` is 900 000 milliseconds which is 15 minutes. Did you wait long enough for the task to repeat?

Comment: i found this out an hour ago, the hard way.. so I put 15 minutes and voila !  Please post this answer for some points

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation [states](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) **The repeat interval must be greater than or equal to PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS**. The interval is defaulted to `MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS` (which is 15 minutes) if the value passed is less then `MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS`. So, it is just neccessary to wait enough for the PeriodicWorkRequest to repeat. [This guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) can be useful to review the background processing approach and choose the appropriate tool.